# PowerShell and CSV files

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a script, that runs with a `for` loop.

It outputs 3 variables: `$A`, `$B` and `$C`.

I would like at each iteration to outout those 3 variables onto the same line inside a file, instead of the standard output (each of them separaed by a comma).
I would like to add a header. I am cerating a CSV file.

I have seen several way to output variable inside a CSV file, but not inside a `for` loop.

Any way to concatenate those 3 variables and append them to a file?

```
Write-Host $A ',' $B ',' $C | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\TEST.csv -Append
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$A = 'foo'
$B = 'bar'
$C = 'baz'
"$A,$B,$C" # outputs Foo,Bar,Baz
```

However, if you're working with CSVs, the preferred method is to use `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv`, which handles the formatting for you.

Answer (score 0):

`Write-Host` output goes directly to the host console. It cannot be pipelined. Also, as has already been mentioned, you normally want to use the `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` cmdlets when dealing with CSVs (particularly since you want a CSV with headers).

To get a bunch of variables in a form that is exportable by `Export-Csv` construct a custom object like this:

```
New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    'X' = $A
    'Y' = $B
    'Z' = $C
} | Export-Csv 'C:\Temp\test.csv' -NoType
```

The keys of the property hashtable become the column titles of the CSV.

Since you say you want to export data from a `for` loop you'll need to add the parameter `-Append` to `Export-Csv`:

```
for (...) {
    New-Object ... | Export-Csv 'C:\Temp\test.csv' -NoType -Append
}
```

That is because `for` loops don't write to the pipeline, meaning that something like this won't work:

```
for (...) {
    New-Object ...
} | Export-Csv 'C:\Temp\test.csv' -NoType
```

However, depending on what your actual loop looks like you might be able to substitute it with a combination of the range operator (`..`) and a `ForEach-Object` loop:

```
1..5 | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object ...
} | Export-Csv 'C:\Temp\test.csv' -NoType
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided `at each iteration to outout those 3 variables` is **not** meant literal,
you could gather the for loops output in a variable via a `PSCustomObject` and then `Export-Csv` the result.

For demonstration a simple counting loop:

```
$Result = for ($i=1;$i -lt 5;$i++){[pscustomobject]@{X=$i;Y=$i+1;Z=$i+2}}
$Result

X Y Z
- - -
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
4 5 6
```

Then Export/ConvertTo-Csv:

```
$Result|ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
"X","Y","Z"
"1","2","3"
"2","3","4"
"3","4","5"
"4","5","6"
```